# Unity, Class on instantiated prefab is different between objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Odd question here - I have a gameobject with a class object attached. I instantiate the gameobject, and assign the class object with data from an existing class.

I then instantiate a second gameobject with the exact same class object attached and assign it the same data as the first object. If I modify the class attached to the first gameobject, it is different to the class attached to the second object, even though they both reference (or should) reference the same original class.

Can anyone think why this would happen?

Comment: Its because the instances are different. Just because they use the same script doesnt mean its the same instance. gameobject1 instance is unique to gameobject2 and so are their child scripts.

Comment: If you want multiple objects to have the same data, you need a global values to update them with.

Answer (score 0):

if you make the variables you want to persist in the class your adding static, it will use the same instance for both cases, modifying both when you mod one.

check out this enemy class from unity3d's own dev pages

https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/statics

using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

```
public class Enemy
{
//Static variables are shared across all instances
//of a class.
public static int enemyCount = 0;

public Enemy()
{
    //Increment the static variable to know how many
    //objects of this class have been created.
    enemyCount++;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

They are different instances of the same class, they don't reference the same class.
You should write a duplicate method to duplicate the values